# jQuery - make value of Input radio and select option the same

Tags: jquery, forms

I am making  and  values identical.

What I would to do is that if `<select value="Other-Xx">` is selected then it changes `<input type=radio value="Other">`. (* Xx right after 'Other-' is an unspecified text.)

Meanwhile if `<input type=radio value="Other">` is selected, unselect any `<select>` option or reset the `<select>`.

```js
$('.dropdown, input[name="fruits"]').change(updateElements);

function updateElements(e) {
    var $element = $(e.target),
        valueAttribute = '[value="' + $element[0].value + '"]';
    
    if ($element.is(':radio')) {
        $('.dropdown option' + valueAttribute).prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        $('input[name="fruits"]' + valueAttribute).prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select id="SelOpt" class="dropdown">
        <option value="select" selected disabled>--Select--</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
        <option value="Other-Aa">Other A</option>
        <option value="Other-Bb">Other B</option>
        <option value="Other-Cc">Other C</option>
        <option value="Other-Dd">Other D</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
    <input type="radio" value="Apple" name="fruits" />Apple</label>
    <input type="radio" value="Banana" name="fruits" />Banana</label>
    <input type="radio" value="Cherry" name="fruits" />Cherry</label>
    <input type="radio" value="Other" name="fruits" />Others</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate events for each input and perform the actions you want. I was not sure whether you only wanted the change on "Other-xx" or all dropdown elements. I went with the second guess but you can easily adjust it accordingly.

```js
let dropdown = jQuery(".dropdown");
let fruits = jQuery("input[name='fruits']");

dropdown.on("change", function() {
  let value = jQuery(this).val().split("-");
  fruits.filter("[value='" + value[0] + "']").prop("checked", true);
});

fruits.on("change", function() {
  dropdown.val("select");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="SelOpt" class="dropdown">
    <option value="select" selected disabled>--Select--</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
    <option value="Other-Aa">Other A</option>
    <option value="Other-Bb">Other B</option>
    <option value="Other-Cc">Other C</option>
    <option value="Other-Dd">Other D</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="Apple" name="fruits" />Apple</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Banana" name="fruits" />Banana</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Cherry" name="fruits" />Cherry</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Other" name="fruits" />Others</label>
</div>
```